# Perl script using REST::Client works with Perl.exe but not compiled exe

Tags: perl, https

I’ve built a program that uses REST::Client and JSON to communicate with a https rest api. It is a secure server for credit card processing. The program works just fine when I test it using my Perl library and Perl.exe so I know I have all of the necessary modules and dependencies. When I create a compiled .exe using Par::Packer my program doesn’t work. It doesn’t generate any kind of error but I get a 500 response from the https server and the response states
LWP will support https urls if the LWP::Protocol::https module is installed.
When I create the exe the log file states that everything I need is being included but obviously I’m missing something.

Has anyone ever experienced this before?
Any solution?

I have tried everything I can think of.
Help!

Comment: HTTPS isn't supported by LWP out of the box. That's why you needed to install LWP::Protocol::https. And now you need to include it.

Comment: Try adding `-M LWP::Protocol::https` to the compile step. `pp -M LWP::Protocol::https ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strawberry Perl and PAR - run time error on other Windows machine: LWP will support https URLs if the LWP::Protocol::https module is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62462774/strawberry-perl-and-par-run-time-error-on-other-windows-machine-lwp-will-supp)